# How to use jQuery Deferred functionality instead of async.waterfall?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a chain of function calls and use async.waterfall. It works like a charm. But I'd like to do it with jQuery Deferred. How to transform my code?

The example from jQuery site is like this. Both results are passed to `done` function:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

But my code is different. I need to pass a callback to every step of a `waterfall` and I have `if`s in callbacks. How to implement it with jQuery? Is it possible?

```
async.waterfall([
        function(cb) {
            VK.Api.call('users.get', {user_ids: res.session.mid, fields: fields}, function(userDataRes) {
                cb(null, userDataRes);
            });
        },
        function(userDataRes, cb) {
            if(userDataRes.response[0].city) {
                VK.Api.call('database.getCitiesById', {city_ids: userDataRes.response[0].city}, function(cityDataRes) {
                    cb(null, userDataRes, {city: cityDataRes.response[0].name});
                });
            }
            else {
                cb(null, userDataRes, {});
            }
        },
        function(userDataRes, cityDataRes, cb) {
            if(userDataRes.response[0].country) {
                VK.Api.call("database.getCountriesById", {country_ids: userDataRes.response[0].country}, function(countryDataRes) {
                    cb(null, userDataRes, cityDataRes, {country: countryDataRes.response[0].name});
                });
            }
            else {
                cb(null, userDataRes, {}, {});
            }
        },
        function(userDataRes, cityDataRes, countryDataRes, cb) {
            var resObj = $.extend(true, {}, userDataRes.response[0], cityDataRes, countryDataRes);
            cb(null, resObj);
        },
    ],
    function(err, res) {
        console.log("res::: ", res);
    }
);
```

**UPD 1:**

So, I've implemented a solution, but it doesn't work as expected. There is an asynchronous API function call in `.then()` and jQuery deferred flow is broken there. I don't know how to make a `.then()` function as an API callback.

```
var dfr = $.Deferred();

dfr.then(function(val) {

    // THIS is an asynchronous API function call. And its callback returns result that is passed to the next .then()
    // But jQuery deferred flow doesn't follow this API call. 
    // It goes along to the next .then ignoring this API call.
    // How to make it enter this API call and be returned from a API's callback.
    VK.Api.call('users.get', {user_ids: res.session.mid, fields: fields}, function(userDataRes) {
        // cb(null, userDataRes);
        console.log("countryDataRes: ", userDataRes);
        return userDataRes;
    });
}).
then(function(userDataRes) {
    console.log("countryDataRes: ", userDataRes);
    if(userDataRes.response[0].city) {
        VK.Api.call('database.getCitiesById', {city_ids: userDataRes.response[0].city}, function(cityDataRes) {
            // cb(null, userDataRes, {city: cityDataRes.response[0].name});
            return [userDataRes, {city: cityDataRes.response[0].name}];
        });
    }
    else {
        // cb(null, userDataRes, {});
        return [userDataRes, {}];
    }
}).
then(function(aRes) {
    if(aRes[0].response[0].country) {
        VK.Api.call("database.getCountriesById", {country_ids: aRes[0].response[0].country}, function(countryDataRes) {
            // cb(null, userDataRes, cityDataRes, {country: countryDataRes.response[0].name});
            return [aRes[0], aRes[1], {country: countryDataRes.response[0].name}];
        });
    }
    else {
        cb(null, aRes[0], {}, {});
    }
}).
then(function(aRes) {
    var resObj = $.extend(true, {}, aRes[0].response[0], aRes[1], aRes[2]);
    console.log("cityDataRes: ", aRes[1]);
    console.log("countryDataRes: ", aRes[2]);
    cb(null, resObj);
    return resObj;
}).
done(function(res) {
    console.log("res::: ", res);
});

dfr.resolve();
```

Comment: @DevlshOne, That's what I'm trying to do now. But jQuery has different implementation paradigm for this task. And I can't understand how to do it. I'm not asking for a ready result, just a clue. So can you give me any clue about the task or you can just type reproaches?

Comment: Your "clue" is the example given by the jQuery team on how the `.when()` method is used. Show YOUR attempt at implementing it and you'll find the reproaches diminish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with the general rule for using promises:

> **Every function that does something asynchronous must return a promise**

Which functions are these in your case? Basically, the complete waterfall, each of the waterfall functions that took a `cb` and `VK.Api.call`.

Hm, `VK.Api.call` doesn't return a promise, and it's a library function so we cannot modify it. Rule 2 comes into play:

> **[Create an immediate wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) for every function that doesn't**

In our case, it will look like this:

```
function callApi(method, data) {
    var dfr = $.Deferred();
    VK.Api.call(method, data, function(result) {
        dfr.resolve(result);
    });
    // No error callbacks? That's scary!
    // If it does offer one, call `dfr.reject(err)` from it
    return dfr.promise();
}
```

Now we have only promises around, and do no more need any deferreds. Third rule comes into play:

> **Everything that does something with an async result goes into a `.then` callback**
>
> **…and returns its result.**

That result might as well be a promise not a plain value, `.then` can handle these - and will give us back a new promise for the eventual result of executing the "something". So, let's chain some `then()`s:

```
apiCall('users.get', {user_ids: res.session.mid, fields: fields})
.then(function(userDataRes) {
    console.log("countryDataRes: ", userDataRes);
    if (userDataRes.response[0].city) {
        return apiCall('database.getCitiesById', {city_ids: userDataRes.response[0].city})
        .then(function(cityDataRes) {
            return [userDataRes, {city: cityDataRes.response[0].name}];
        });
    } else {
        return [userDataRes, {}];
    }
})
.then(function(aRes) {
    if (aRes[0].response[0].country) {
        return apiCall("database.getCountriesById", {country_ids: aRes[0].response[0].country})
        .then(function(countryDataRes) {
            return [aRes[0], aRes[1], {country: countryDataRes.response[0].name}];
        });
    } else {
        return [aRes[0], aRes[1], {}];
    }
})
.then(function(aRes) {
    var resObj = $.extend(true, {}, aRes[0].response[0], aRes[1], aRes[2]);
    console.log("cityDataRes: ", aRes[1]);
    console.log("countryDataRes: ", aRes[2]);
    return resObj;
})
.done(function(res) {
    console.log("res::: ", res);
});
```

---

At least, that's what your original waterfall did. Let's polish it up a bit by executing `getCitiesById` and `getCountriesById` in parallel, and removing all the boilerplate of explicitly creating these `aRes` arrays.

```
function callApi(method, data) {
    var dfr = $.Deferred();
    VK.Api.call(method, data, function(result) {
        dfr.resolve(result.response[0]);
//               changed: ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
    // No error callbacks? That's scary!
    // If it does offer one, call `dfr.reject(err)` from it
    return dfr.promise();
}
apiCall('users.get', {user_ids: res.session.mid, fields: fields})
.then(function(userData) {
    if (userData.city)
        var cityProm = apiCall('database.getCitiesById', {city_ids: userData.city});
    if (userData.country)
        var countryProm = apiCall("database.getCountriesById", {country_ids: userData.country});
    return $.when(cityProm, countrProm).then(function(city, country) {
        var resObj = $.extend(true, {}, userData);
        if (city)
            resObj.city = city.name;
        if (country)
            resObj.country = country.name;
        return resObj;
    });
})
.done(function(res) {
    console.log("res::: ", res);
});
```